# Load a master data file to spark ecosystem

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

While building a log processing system, I came across a scenario where I need to look up data from a tree file (Like a DB) for each and every log line for corresponding value. What is the best approach to load an external file which is very large into the spark ecosystem? The tree file is of size 2GB.

Here is my scenario

1. I have a file contains huge number of log lines.
2. Each log line needs to be split by a delimiter to 70 fields
3. Need to lookup the data from tree file for one of the 70 fields of a log line.

I am using Apache Spark Python API and running on a 3 node cluster.

Below is the code which I have written. But it is really slow

```
def process_logline(line, tree):
    row_dict = {}
    line_list = line.split(" ")
    row_dict["host"] = tree_lookup_value(tree, line_list[0])
    new_row = Row(**row_dict)
    return new_row

def run_job(vals):
    spark.sparkContext.addFile('somefile')
    tree_val = open(SparkFiles.get('somefile'))
    lines = spark.sparkContext.textFile("log_file")
    converted_lines_rdd = lines.map(lambda l: process_logline(l, tree_val))
    log_line_rdd = spark.createDataFrame(converted_lines_rdd)
    log_line_rdd.show()
```

Comment: I think you can use spark dataframes and load both the files as dataframes and do a join.  That would be faster than using spark-rdd api.

Comment: We can't do a join here since the data is not a pure text file, we need to use this tree_lookup_value method to fetch the data from the tree file.

Comment: In that case you can write a spark UDF (possibly vectorized) and use tree_lookup_value inside the udf. Other Text file can be read as a df and you can apply this udf on that